# 'The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous' - What does that mean?

Tags: python

the following lines of code produce some error and I dont know what the error message really means:

```
config = SHConfig()
if client_id and client_secret:
    config.sh_client_id = client_id
    config.sh_client_secret = client_secret
if config.sh_client_id == '' or config.sh_client_secret == '':
    print("Warning! To use Sentinel Hub services, please provide the credentials (client ID and client secret).")
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

So - how can I handle this?

Comment: 1 or more values in your if statements are DataFrame so it cant be translated to false or true, you need to check if the dataframe.empty and check the .iloc[0] value or the specified column for it. can you check the initiated attributes: (client_id, client_secret) ?

Comment: @ilyashusterman How do I check them?

Comment: print(type(client_id))

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of your variables are pandas dataframes?

Pandas considers `and` and `or` ambiguous and requires bitwise operators `&` and `|`.  Change `and` to `&` and `or` to `|` when comparing dataframes/series.

Comment: Yes, I do use some pandas datastructures, but client_id and client_secret are strings, for which I cannot use the &-operator =/

Comment: can you share what your input looks like (with dummy data)?  is this inside a loop?  Without seeing your data, it's hard to know what to fix, but based on the error some of your variables are seeing by python as dataframes, and you trying to compare them.